# Issue filling a JTable with a List<nftDTO>

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm filling a JTable with a List of 68 nftDTO objects but the model paint only 48  nftDTO objects and I need to paint all of them. I paste the code:

```
private JTable setNftTable() {

    List<NftDTO> nfts = mainWindow.getPeticiones().obtainNftAccount(user.getErd());
    String[] columsName = new String[] { "Nu.","Name", "Collection name", "royalties", "website" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(4, columsName.length);
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columsName);

    for (NftDTO nft : nfts) {
        System.out.println(nft.getNftUrl());
        if(nft.getNftUrl()==null) {
            nft.setNftUrl("there is no URL");
        }
        model.addRow(
                new Object[] { countNft(), nft.getNftName(), nft.getColletionName(), nft.getRoyalties(), nft.getNftUrl() });
    }
    model.removeRow(0);
    model.removeRow(1);
    nftTable = new JTable(model);
    nftTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 800));

    return nftTable;
}
```

I paste by the way the list i receive and the painting of the method
[The list I recieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0JUu.jpg),
[the painting result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5kMg.jpg)
Any suggestion on how can I put all the objects on the JTable?

Comment: I can't tell from this tiny segment of code.  Update your question with a [mre] and be sure to use Swing layout managers to place the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane` on the `JFrame`.

Comment: Don't use `setPrefeeredSize()`. Scrolling won't work properly if you hard code the value. The table will automatically calculate the preferred size based on the number of rows of data added to the model.

Comment: as camickr said, after deleting setPreferredSize() the JTable showed all the elements